# Can I use my computer as a Java server?

Tags: java, server

I'm attempting to make a simple server in Java that can communicate with my friends through another Java program, A simple client. I know that I can use localhost to test the program, but if I change the host setting in it to my computers ip address and run the server on my personal computer, then run the client on a different computer, will my computer act as a server?

Comment: Short answer: yes. But your question will be closed for being too broad.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can - when a Client wants to connect to a Server (using java sockets you described above) it needs to specify the Server's IP Address and a Port to connect through, so your own computer can act as a Server and you will need to provide your IP Address and an open port to Clients